# I need a deep explanation of JavaScript Iterables.

Tags: javascript

Why we need them and how they are used as well as adding the Iterable functionality to an object that does not have it. This seems like a topic only skimmed over in general.

Comment: http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_iteration.html

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols

Comment: To the close/down voters, while this material is pretty well covered elsewhere I'm unable to find an place where it's been covered here on SO. If you still feel it's worthy of closing/downvoting that's your right, but since it's not a dupe and not (in my opinion) too broad I answered it.

Comment: I agree fully. This question has definitely not been answered in detail anywhere on SO, thus leading to me asking the legitimate question.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript iterators use the well-known Symbol [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator) to define a function that when called returns an object. That object has a method `next` which returns another object that has two properties: `value` (the current value of the iterator) and `done` (whether or not the iterator is finished). Example:

```
const foo = {};
foo[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
  let i = 0;
  yield ++i;
};

let iter = foo[Symbol.iterator]();
iter.next(); // { value: 1, done: false }
iter.next(); // { value: 2, done: false }
```

Note that the `*` denotes a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*).

Iterators can also be used with automatic constructs like `for..of`. The one I defined above however will not work with `for..of` because it never finishes: looping through all of its properties would eventually lead to running out of memory. So lets use an array:

```
const bar = [1,2];
for (let baz of bar) console.log(baz); // logs 1, 2, stops
```

All of the built in collections (except the weak ones) can be iterated this way as they implement this interface.

Iterables that hold on to a resource like a file handle may be explicitly closed if the caller is done with them prior to their being exhausted. For an example we'll use a hypothetical file API with `readFromFile` and `getNextLine` functions:

```
const fileReader = {
  [Symbol.iterator] (path) {
    return {
      fileHandle: readFromFile(path),
      next () {
        return {
          value: this.fileHandle.getNextLine(),
          done: false
        }
      }

      return () {
        this.fileHandle.close();
      }
    }
  }
};
```

You can call the `return` method to prevent leaking the file handle. See [this post](http://raganwald.com/2017/07/22/closing-iterables-is-a-leaky-abstraction.html) by Reg Braithwaite for more. Also note that since we're explicitly defining the iterator returned by the method, we don't need to make it a generator function.

If your iterator is a generator function as in my infinite list of counting numbers above, you may [pass it values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Advanced_generators) via the `yield` keyword:

```
foo[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
  let i = 0;
  let reset = yield ++i;
  if (reset) i = 0;
};

iter = foo[Symbol.iterator]();
iter.next().value;    // 1
iter.next().value     // 2
iter.next(true).value // 1 again
```

So let's say you have some object `myObject` that you want to be able to iterate the properties of. We'll ignore `Object.entries` for the next example:

```
const myObject = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};

Object.defineProperty(myObject, Symbol.iterator, {
  value: function* () {
    for (let key in myObject) {
      if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        yield [key, myObject[key]];
      }
    }
  }
});

iter = myObject[Symbol.iterator]();
iter.next(); // { value: ['a', 1], done: false }
iter.next(); // { value: ['b', 2], done: false }
iter.next(); // { value: undefined, done: true }
```

#### NOTE

Prior to ES 2015 object properties were not guaranteed to have order. The above code all works fine if you run it in the most recent Chrome/FF/Safari, but if you transpile this for older browsers you might see `['b', 2]` output first, or not, or it could change each time you iterate.

And now you probably know more about JavaScript iterables than you really wanted to.