# IterableIterator in ES2015 - What is it?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

When I implement the interface array, there are methods there return an IterableIterator.
The IterableIterator extends from Iterator that I can understand well and makes sense to me.

```
interface IterableIterator<T> extends Iterator<T> {
    [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<T>;
}
```

But what should I implement for Symbol.iterator. This also return an IterableIterator (recursion?)
I don't understand the concept of IterableIterator.
It would be great if someone could respond. Or could give me a source where this is described.

Comment: TL;DR just use a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) and yield the elements of the array one at a time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46218959/3757232

Comment: **It's explained in detail [here](https://www.geekabyte.io/2019/06/typing-iterables-and-iterators-with.html):** *"`IterableIterator` is an interface defined by TypeScript that combines the contracts of Iterables and Iterator into one. This is because, in some cases, it makes sense to have the Iterable as an Iterator itself, removing the need to have an external class that serves as the iterator."*

Comment: Iterable + Iterator (make sense for me) is not IterableIterator
The Difference is that Symbol.iterator from Iterable gives a Iterator (make sense for me) and IterableIterator gives IterableIterator.
What is the gain to use IterableIterator instead Iterable + Iterator (is not the same)?

Comment: They're the same. It's just a convenience.

Answer (score 9):

It is often useful for `Iterator` objects to become `Iterable` themselves, so that they can:

- be used in a `for..of` loop
- be spread into an array
- be spread into a parameter list
- be used in APIs that accept iterables like

  - `Array.from`
  - `new Set`
  - `new Map`

If an `Iterator` object is not `Iterable`, then they can’t be used in ways described above. The only way to iterate through it is to repeatedly call the `.next()` method. This is inconvenient. Therefore, [most `Iterator` objects produced by ECMAScript APIs](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-%iteratorprototype%-object) are also `Iterable`.

To make an `Iterator` `Iterable`, [the `[Symbol.iterator]` method should `return this`](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-%iteratorprototype%-@@iterator).

For more information see:

- [“Iteration protocols” on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols)
- [“Implementing iterables” in *Exploring ES6*](https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_iteration.html#sec_implementing-iterables), which also talks about “Iterators that are iterable”